# Narrator does not read check box status when set programmatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, accessibility, narrator

I have a listbox which uses the datatemplate to generate a list of checkboxes. The issue is when using the keyboard , the focus moves twice over the item. Once because of the list item and next for the checkbox. In order to change this in my code-behind, I set the checkbox IsChecked to True when Space is pressed for the list item. The issue is , the narrator reads the 'Space' instead of mentioning the 'checked' or 'unchecked' status of the checkbox. I understand this is because the foucs is on the list control and not the checkbox control. Is there a way for the narrator to read 'checked' without having the focus?